# Convolution of integer sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convolution

I read this somewhere:

$U$ and $V$ are defined on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers. The convolution of $u$ and $v$, noted as $(u*v) (k)\,\theta$ or $ (u \otimes v) (k)\theta$, is a new sequence whose general term is given by
$(u*v) (k) = (u \otimes v) (k) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} u(i)v(k-i)\theta$

Can I take $\{-1, -2, -3, \ldots\}$ for $U$ and $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ for $V$?

How to interpret this: $(u*v) (k)\,\theta$

Why do we insert this part $ (k) \,\theta$ in the formula?

Why does $i$ go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Could someone give me an example of this formula?

Comment: What is the $\theta$?

Comment: There's no $\theta$!

Comment: @sbr Both me and copper.hat must be hallucinating.

Comment: $\Theta$here are $\theta$he$\theta$as.

Comment: $\theta$ere are $\theta$etas!

Comment: $K \alpha \lambda \alpha$!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write
$$
(u*v)(k) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(k-i).
$$

I have no idea what the letter $\theta$ is doing there.  As to why the $k$ is there, it's because you want to define
$$
\ldots\ldots, (u*v)(-3), (u*v)(-2), (u*v)(-1), (u*v)(0), (u*v)(1), (u*v)(2), (u*v)(3), \ldots\ldots
$$
etc.  The number in the parentheses is $k$.  Thus, for example, when $k=4$, we have
\begin{align}
(u*v)(4) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(4-i)
\end{align}
$$
= \cdots\cdots+u(-3)v(7)+u(-2)v(6)+u(-1)v(5)+u(0)v(4)+u(1)v(3)+u(2)v(2)
$$
$$
\phantom{={}} {}+u(3)v(1)+ u(4)v(0) + u(5) v(-1) + u(6)v(-2)+u(7)v(-3)+u(8)v(-4)+\cdots\cdots.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but what to do with u(-3)v(7)? Should there be a function u and v in there? E.g. U(-3)=(-3)^2+blahblahblah and the same for v(7)? Or do I need to multiply -3 with 7? But how do I suppose to get any number out of the multiplication if it goes to infinity?

Comment: The two functions $u$ and $v$ are both there.  As for going to infinity, infinite series can converge.

Comment: Sorry, i mean that it looked like you were trying to evaluate functions, as in a "f(x)=" style. But you didn't define u(x)= and v(x)=

Comment: Evaluating functions is exactly what I was referring to.  When one writes $u(4)$, that means the value of the function $u$ when its input is $4$.  As for what functions $u$ and $v$ are, they are whichever functions you are convolving.  They could be any two functions whose domain is the set of all integers.

Comment: It doesn't feel that intuitive that you should multiply a value at -3 with a value at 7? Could you explain that in an intuitive way?

Answer (score 1):

The $k$ in the formula indicates that you are talking about the $k$th term in the sequence $u\ast v$.

I do not know for sure what the $\theta$ adds anything, unless that is part of the author's notation for making a modification of these sequences.

If summed from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, that sum is often going to be divergent: is it possible the $\theta$ is some restriction that zeros out all but finitely many terms of the series? Please consult your source.

As for "give me an example":

Take $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to be integer polynomials, and then interpret them as sequences in the obvious way: i.e. you put the $i$th term to be the coefficient of $x^i$. Then you'll find that $u\ast v$ is the sequence representing the coefficients of $u(x)v(x)$!

Example: $u(x)=x-2$, $v(x)=3x^2+x$. The sequences are:
$$
\dots u_{-2}=u_{-1}=0;\  \ u_0=-2;\  \ u_1=1; \  \ u_2=u_3=\dots=0
$$
$$
\dots v_{-2}=v_{-1}=v_0=0;\  \ v_1=1;\  \ v_2=3;\  \ v_3=v_4=\dots=0
$$

The convoluted sequence is:

$$
\dots (v\ast u)_{-2}=(v\ast u)_{-1}=(v\ast u)_0=0;\  \ (v\ast u)_1=-2;\  \ (v\ast u)_2=-5;\  \ (v\ast u)_3=3;\  \ (v\ast u)_4=(v\ast u)_5=\dots=0
$$

And that turns out to be exactly the sequence for $u(x)v(x)=3x^3-5x^2-2x$.

You can use this to show that the sequences of finite support contained in the nonnegative integers, equipped with the $\ast$ operation are isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. If you consider *all* sequences of finite support, then that is isomorphic to the "Laurent polynomials" $\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: Please elaborate on "then interpret them as sequences in the obvious way: i.e. you put the $i$th term to be the coefficient of $x^i$. Then you'll find that $u\ast v$ is the sequence representing the coefficients of $u(x)v(x)$!" in simple english

Comment: Take for example $u(x)=x^2$ and $v(x)=1+x^3$. Then the sequence for $u$ is $u_2=1$ and $u_k=0$ for $k\neq 2$. The sequence for $v$ is $v_0=v_3=1$ and $v_k=0$ for other $k$. If you take the convolution of these two sequences, you will get $(u\ast v)_2=(u\ast v)_5=1$, and $(u\ast v)_k=0$ otherwise. That is the sequence for $x^5+x^2=u(x)v(x)$!

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the math notations algebraically? You say "you put the ith term to be the coefficient of x^i" What does that mean?

Comment: @user1095340 There is no algebra to it. I'm just saying that *the coefficients of a polynomial form a sequence indexed by integers*. Elements of the sequence with negative indices are all zero, and the $k$th term of the sequence is just the coefficient of $x^k$. The example in my last comment and the example in the post should illustrate this very well...

Comment: I didn't fully understand why u1 = 1 and not u1 = u(1)=1-2=-1 and why v1=1 and not v1 = v(1)=3*1^2+1=4, etc, etc... The problem could be my understanding of the English language, but you say that "Elements of the sequence with negative indices are all zero", but in the example in the post, v3, v4, v5, etc, etc, are zero as well... The number  3,4 and 5 are not negative indexnumbers! And v3 is not 0, when you take v3=3*(V2)^2+V2=3*3^2+3=3*9+3=27+3=30 and it also isn't 0, when you take v(x)=3x^2+x for x=3: v(3)=3*3^2+3=3*9+3=27+3=30

Comment: @user1095340 Ah! I see part of the misunderstanding. At no point are we evaluating polynomials. If $f$ is a function on the integers, then I am preferring to write $f(z)$ as $f_z$, so as to avoid this confusion. Picture the sequence of $f_z$ in order (z=...-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3...). For the polynomial $v$ in my comment the sequence of $f_z$ becomes: ...0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0... which corresponds to $\dots 0x^{-3}+0x^{-2}+0x^{-1}+1x^0+0x^1+0x^2+1x^3+0x^4\dots$. The first thing is a sequence, the second thing is a polynomial (with that sequence of coefficients.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes things more clear for me! :) - Could you comment on Michael Hardy's method. And also the ∑ in the formula, please. When do I need to compute the sum? And when should I simply using something like $u(x)v(x)=3x^3-5x^2-2x$

Comment: @user1095340 I don't know what you mean by "his method." We have said the exact same thing, just with our own examples. The formula you wrote is the formula for an individual term of the convoluted series. You have to perform the sum on each $k$. If your two functions have finite support, then you can write them as polynomials with integer powers, and then multiply them normally, to compute the convolution.

Comment: "You have to perform the sum on each k". How? Which numbers should I use for k? (-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3??? | where are the limits for k=[ from minus infinity to infinity]?) Where should put the value k in your example? Since you didn't use k in your example.  And how to compute the sum? Just taking: "3x^3−5x^2−2x" with a domain of lets say [0, 4] and integrate that or something? or do I need to have a different domain? And do I need to integrate something else? And what to do with the sum?

Comment: @user1095340 Oh! Two comments ago I used $z$ for an integer instead of $k$. Every integer $k$ labels an element of the sequence (e.g. $u_k$). If you replace all the $z$'s in that comment with $k$'s, that is fine. The $k$'s act as subscripts only. You do not need to pick a domain, and this has nothing to do with integration. I am not sure what problem you are having with the sum. You might consider picking two of the example sequences someone has given, and posting it as a "I'm having trouble using convolution on these sequences" problem.

Comment: @user1095340 Here is the formula as I would write it: 

$(u*v)_k = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u_iv_{k-i}. $ By performing the sum for each $k$, you will produce the elements of a sequence called $u\ast v$. I like the subscript notation a little better for sequences. Just keep in mind that $f_x$ and $f(x)$ are just two ways of writing a function of $x$.

Comment: "$$3x^3−5x^2−2x$$" doesn't the formula suppose to converge?

Comment: @user1095340 Since there are only finitely many nonzero coefficients, it *must* converge.

Comment: #rschwieb: That's confusing me... Azimut wrote 'Since $\lim_{i\to \infty} i^3 = \infty$, this clearly isn't convergent for any $k$.' http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326707/what-is-absolute-convergence

Comment: Question b: What is the benefit of writting the multiplication the way you described? Instead of just: $(x-2)(3x^2+x)=3x^3+x^2-2*3x^2-2x=3x^3+x^2-6x^2-2x=3x^3-5x^2-2x$

Comment: @user1095340 Answer a) I cannot see any comment by Azimut. But if you (correctly) write out the convolution of the two polynomials in my post, that is what you'll get. If you are making a mistake, I will have no idea where it is until you show me your work. Answer b) Who said there is a benefit? I just said that the convolution extends the ordinary polynomial product...

Comment: "I cannot see any comment by Azimut" - What do you mean? You can't open the link? It was provided as answer for this question?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326707

Comment: @user1095340 Thanks, I thought you were referring to something in this post. I'll try to answer there.