# A question about Riemann sums

Tags: notation

Take: 
$$
(u*v)(k) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(k-i).
$$

$k$ is there, it's because you want to define
$$
\ldots\ldots, (u*v)(-3), (u*v)(-2), (u*v)(-1), (u*v)(0), (u*v)(1), (u*v)(2), (u*v)(3), \ldots\ldots
$$
etc.  The number in the parentheses is $k$.  Thus, for example, when $k=4$, we have
\begin{align}
(u*v)(4) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty u(i)v(4-i)
\end{align}
$$
= \cdots\cdots+u(-3)v(7)+u(-2)v(6)+u(-1)v(5)+u(0)v(4)+u(1)v(3)+u(2)v(2)
$$
$$
\phantom{={}} {}+u(3)v(1)+ u(4)v(0) + u(5) v(-1) + u(6)v(-2)+u(7)v(-3)+u(8)v(-4)+\cdots\cdots.
$$

What does a notation like $u(3)v(1)$ mean? What should I do with the number 3 and the number 1?

Comment: How is this a question about Riemann integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ and $v$ are two fixed *functions*. As functions, they can be evaluated.
The expression $u(3)v(1)$ means: evaluate the function $u$ at $3$, evaluate the function $v$ at $1$, and then multiply those two results.

Example: if $u(x) = x^2$ and $v(x) = x+5$, then $u(3)v(1) = 3^2\cdot(1+5) = 54$.

Comment: How? What whould be the result?

Comment: The result depends on the definition of the functions $u$ and $v$, of course.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Check Michael Hardy's answer. He says "The two functions u and v are both there" I guess I suffer a very rare type of math blindness ;)  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323000/convolution-of-integer-sequences

Comment: Lets take  $u(x)=x-2$, $v(x)=3x^2+x$

Comment: Yeah, feel free to repeat this with any pair of functions you like :)

Comment: Do those functions converge? Is it possible to get any value out of it? Or do they just diverge?

Comment: I don't see the connection, is this a new question? If yes, please open a new question for it (and finish this one by accepting my answer).