# What does $\propto$ mean?

Tags: notation

From [this article](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/deconvLevinEtalCVPR09.pdf):

> $\ldots$a maximum-a-postiori "a maximum-a-posteriori
>   $(MAP_{x,k}^{\,\,\,\,\,1})$ estimation, seeking a pair $(\hat{x}, \hat{k})$ maximizing:
>   $$p(x, k\mid y) \propto p(y\mid x, k)p(x)p(k).$$

What does the symbol '∝' mean in this context?

Comment: I think Seyhmus Güngören's answer is vague.  It's just how this question is usually answered, and I think it bears elaboration.

Comment: Bernoulli used it to mean "$=$".

Comment: Another question, are "x hat" and "k hat" the normalized version of vector x and k, having length 1? And why does this make sense?

Comment: $\hat x$ and $\hat k$ are the values of $x$ and $k$ that make $p(x,k\mid y)$ as large as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means proportional as a function of two variables $x$ and $k$ with $y$ fixed.

You have a prior probability density as a function of $x$ and $k$, which is just a product of a function of $x$ and a function of $k$, so that the random variables involved are independent in the prior distribution.  Then new data arrives: a random variable is observed to be equal to a number $y$.  The conditional density of that random variable given that the first two were equal to $x$ and $k$, is the first factor in the expression on the right.

The expression on the left is the conditional density of the random variables corresponding to $x$ and $k$ given that observed value equal to $y$.

Since it means proportional as a function of $x$ and $k$ with $y$ fixed, you need to multiply it by a normalizing constant that may depend on $y$ but does not depend on $x$ and $k$, in order to make it a probability density function, as a function of $x$ and $k$.  "Constant" in this case would mean not depending on $x$ and $k$.

"Constant" always means not depending on something.  Usually it's clear from the context what the "something" is, but I think it should be stated explicitly more often than it is in present-day conventional practice.  Here's a favorite example of mine, involving differentiation of exponential functions:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} 2^x & = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^{x+h}-2^x}{h} \\[10pt]
& = 2^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^h-1}{h}\tag{1} \\[10pt]
& = (2^x\cdot\text{constant})\tag{2}.
\end{align}

In $(1)$, the factor $2^x$ can be taken out of the limit because it's "constant" but "constant" means not depending on $h$.

In $(2)$, "constant" means not depending on $x$.

Some instructors in calculus classes actually present this proof without mentioning the contextual change in the meaning of "constant".

**Later note in response to comments below:** The linked paper uses a rather obnoxious notation, $p(x)$ and $p(k)$ for the probability density functions of two different random variables.  One should distinguish between capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ in expressions like $\Pr(X=x)$, where capital $X$ is a random variable and lower-case $x$ is a particular value that $X$ might be equal to.  Then, if one writes $p_X(x)$ for the value of the probability density function of a random variable (capital) $X$ at the point (lower-case) $x$, then one knows that $p_X(3)$ means something different from $p_Y(3)$.

But at any rate, $p(x)p(k)$ is the notation used in the linked paper for the joint density function of a pair of independent random variables, and $p(y\mid x,k)$ is the conditional density of another random variable given the values of those two.  The idea is that if you multiply those, what you get is **proportional**, as a function of $x$ and $k$ with $y$ fixed, to the conditional density function of the random variables corresponding to $x$ and $k$, given an observed value of the random variable corresponding to $y$.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, and btw. Could you answer my comments on your answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323000/convolution-of-integer-sequences

Comment: Since, I don't know much about statistics, I would like to ask you: Could you go through it, step-by-step, referring to which part of the formula you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

The symbol you've written means propotional. Check:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: But does it mean proportional as a function of $x$ with $k$ and $y$ fixed, or proportional as a function of $y$ with $k$ and $x$ fixed, or proportional as a function of $k$ with $x$ and $y$ fixed?  My guess is none of the above: it means proportional as a function of two variables $x$ and $k$ with $y$ fixed.

Comment: Thanks, now, how to interpret it, if you want to write it as one sentence? So, lets say if you want to explain it to a non-mathperson.

Comment: It means right and left hand side of the equation behaves similarly. Can happen that there is a simple constant factor. For each equality one can use this term. Additionally whenever this term is used, left hand side can be obtained from the right hand side by just a simple scaling. Examples: "If an object travels at a constant speed, then the distance traveled is directly proportional to the time spent traveling, with the speed being the constant of proportionality."
"The circumference of a circle is directly proportional to its diameter, with the constant of proportionality equal to $\pi$.

Comment: . . . and my comment stands, for reasons that I think should be clear if you read the answer I posted.

Comment: It is **MAP**. So the difference between **ML** is the *a priori* probabilities, which are taken As some scaling factors in **MAP**. Therefore $p(x)$ and $p(k)$ in this context are jointly the scaling factor.

Comment: It might also happen that he is indicating the independecy between $T$ and $X$.  One should see more about the content