# What does $\propto$ mean in the following equation?

Tags: notation

I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328925/what-does-propto-mean) but I still have problem with the meaning of this symbol. From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=1nAvp2HW_gwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=polarimetric%20radar%20imaging&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIpOrww_nExwIVyOkUCh2JcQgH#v=onepage&q=polarimetric%20radar%20imaging&f=false):

> The time-dependent angle may be defined from the components of the
>   wave vector in order to determine its sense of rotation
>   $$\tan\xi(t)=\frac{E_y(z_0,t)}{E_x(z_0,t)}=\frac{E_{0y}\cos(\omega
> t-kz_0+\delta_y)}{E_{0x}\cos (\omega t-kz_0+\delta_x)}$$   The sense
>   of rotation may then be related to the sign of the ellipticity $\tau$,
>   with   $$\frac{\partial \xi(t)}{\partial
> t}\propto-\sin\delta\Rightarrow \text{sign}\left(\frac{\partial\xi(t)}{\partial t}\right)=-\text{sign}(\tau)$$

What does the symbol '$\propto$' mean in this context?

Comment: Mightn't it mean "proportional to," as it often does?

Comment: Your [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328925/what-does-propto-mean) explains it, does it not ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Does it mean that $\frac{\partial \xi(t)}{\partial t}$ is proportional to $-\sin\delta$? Then how do we conclude from that $\text{sign}\left(\frac{\partial\xi(t)}{\partial t}\right)=-\text{sign}(\tau)$?

Comment: That will probably be hard to say without looking at the original. The likelihood that someone will scan the ~400 pages of the book for that equation when you could have just provided the page number is rather low.

Comment: ok @joriki It's on page 36

Answer (score 2):

This symbol means "proportional to". Generally it might be taken to include the case of a negative constant of proportionality, but here the minus sign would seem to indicate that the intended meaning is with a positive constant of proportionality. The right-hand side of the implication then follows in view of equation $(2.20)$ in the book, taking into account that $|\tau|\in[0,\frac\pi4]$ and that $E_{0x}$ and $E_{0y}$ are amplitudes and hence positive.